# Check the presence of an element's attribute - protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am fairly new to protractor and angularJS so please help me with this. When the `dayReport` element is selected, the `class='active'` attribute is set but when the element is not selected, the attribute is completely removed.

I want to make sure that when another element is selected, `dayReport` doesn't have the `class='active'` attribute although the element itself is still present.

I tried this: `expect(dayReport.getAttribute('class').isPresent()).toBe(false);` and some other few ideas but it I don't seem to make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For whoever is reading this and needs a clear answer, the response from @TomNijs was very helpful but the `hasClass` function should be created in order for that to work. So the whole piece of code after defining the `dayReport` element is now looking like this:

```
  var hasClass = function (element, cls)
  {
    return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes)
    {
      return classes.split(' ').indexOf(cls) !== -1;
    });
  };

  expect(hasClass(dayReport, 'active')).toBe(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, try the following code :
`hasClass` will return a promise which will immediatly be resolved by the `expect`statement and return true or false wether your element has the `class="active"` attribute.

```
//hasClass will check if the first parameter (the element) has the following the second parameter(the class attribute)
expect(hasClass(dayReport, 'active')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: There are lots of other elements with `class="active"`  but I'm interested in checking this specific `dayReport` element. Since there are lots of other elements with that class, with your code I will always get `true` for `isPresent()` although it's not true for my element specifically.

Comment: @LiviuP Thanks for your reply, I've updated the answer, this requires you to have a variable dayReport which holds the element in question. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your update. It works but for those who will read this, you have to know that the `hasClass` function has to be created prior of running the expect statement. So the whole code for this should look like this:

     var hasClass = function (element, cls)
      {
        return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes)
        {
          return classes.split(' ').indexOf(cls) !== -1;
        });
      };

      expect(hasClass(dayReport, 'active')).toBe(false);

Comment: @LiviuP You could post an answer to your own question to clarify this to other users.